# python selenium - is_enabled returns True even when button is disabled

Tags: python-3.x, angular, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a button which is disabled until username, password is filled in. I tried simple code snippet as follows:

```
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpathOfSubmitButton)
    print(e.is_enabled())
```

Output: True

What I want to achieve is to check if the button is disabled until all values are correctly filled.

Note: Our website is Angular 9 based, if that could make a difference, please let me know.

I am fairly new to Selenium hence any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I believe you mean element by using e.is_enabled(). Also can you please HTML code for your button ?

Comment: When you say the button is "disabled", are you sure it's not just invisible?